# Remotely start Android phone

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an anti-theft program for Android phones (I do my tests and debug on a Google Nexus 4 phone) and currently searching for solutions to remotely interact with the phone.

**Is there any way to powerup an Android phone remotely?**

Comment: Have you tried to send hot Gynoid images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as the phone is off, there's no network connection to allow it to receive any kind of "turn on" command. So, the answer is a simple "no".

Comment: Maybe there's some way to have a piece of code inside the phone that powers it up from time to time to interact through a network connection?

Comment: You could _maybe_ do that if you modified some very low-level OS code on the device, but there's nothing that is exposed via the Android APIs that would allow you to do that for a consumer application